# 2d array from c++ to lua

Tags: c++, arrays, multidimensional-array, lua, luabind

So,is Passing a multidimensional array from C++ to Lua actually possible?

Or should I just make it a normal array,pass it to Lua and convert it there to a 2d array again?

And if its possible lets say I've got this

```
function AI(Array)
-- can I just call it like this?
   num= Array[1][2];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well it seems like at least as far as i saw you cant do this so the best option is just to send it like a unidimensional array and then convert it back in LUA

Answer (score 0):

May be something like a binding library would be of help
http://sourceforge.net/projects/luabind/